# Web App not serving static resources using Spring Boot and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat7, spring-boot

Hello I am having troubles 'serving' resources with my web server, while some of my other resources are 'serving.'  (graphs.js is loading)

In my browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/js/app.js [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 2ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/includes/header.html [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 4ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/cs/bootstrap.min.css [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 3ms]
```

But these files are located in my directory as such:

```
css/
    bootstrap.min.css
includes/
    header.html
js/
    app.js
    controllers/
        graphs.js
```

When my server starts:

```
2014-07-28 08:25:06.748  INFO 5260 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2014-07-28 08:25:06.939  INFO 5260 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2014-07-28 08:25:06.940  INFO 5260 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
2014-07-28 08:25:07.017  INFO 5260 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-07-28 08:25:07.017  INFO 5260 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1146 ms
2014-07-28 08:25:07.346  INFO 5260 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
**mapping**
2014-07-28 08:25:07.903  INFO 5260 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.c.a.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter      : Adding welcome page: jndi:/localhost/index.html
2014-07-28 08:25:07.905  INFO 5260 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2014-07-28 08:25:07.912  INFO 5260 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-07-28 08:25:07.912  INFO 5260 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-07-28 08:25:08.023  INFO 5260 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-07-28 08:25:08.147  INFO 5260 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
2014-07-28 08:25:08.149  INFO 5260 --- [           main] c.c.i.qualifier.datacentral.Application  : Started Application in 2.556 seconds (JVM running for 2.783)
```

and my HTML is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/graphs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not stated if you have followed instructions for packaging as a war instead of a JAR and bundling Tomcat in. This does change things a little. Either way, take a look at the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Bascally, out of the box, you can place static content in one of the locations mentioned: /static, /public, /resources or /META-INF/resorces. As for the location of these folders, well either at the root of the servlet context or on the classpath.

You can find a very basic Tomcat application here: https://github.com/mmeany/spring-boot-web-mvc that does the job.